# Does C++ automatically commute some operation overloads?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I've been trying to understand operation overloading and the commutative property between classes and fundamental types. I declared the Test to Int asterisk operation but not the Int to Test, just to see if C++ would automatically provide with some sort of commutative function. The testing code is:

```
#include <iostream>

class Test{
public:
    float x;

    Test(){
        x = 1;
    }
    Test(float number){
        x = number;
    }
    ~Test(){}
};

Test operator*(Test a, int b){
    std::cout << "Alert! Test to Int happened! ";
    return Test(a.x * b);
}

Test operator*(Test a, Test b){
    std::cout << "Alert! Test to Test happened! ";
    return Test(a.x * b.x);
}

int main(){
    
    Test my_test;
    std::cout << "First result: " << (my_test * 2).x << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Second result: " << (3 * my_test).x << std::endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```

with output:

> *First result: Alert! Test to Int happened! 2*
> *Second result: Alert! Test to Test happened! 3*

The first result was as expected, but for the second result I expected either an error or some unknown-to-me function to do the work. Instead, the Test to Test operation was used... Can someone explain why and what happened?

Comment: Figuring out what happens here is complicated slightly because the implicit ctor takes a `float` but the first `operator*` overload takes an `int`. While this is legal C++, this sort of inconsistency can make error messages difficult to understand.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your constructor with the form of

```
Test(float number){
    x = number;
}
```

is what is called a [converting constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/converting_constructor).  Since it is not `explicit`, it allows you convert a `float` to a `Test` implicitly.  You see that in

```
(3 * my_test).x
```

Here the `3` gets converted to a `float` in the [standard conversion sequence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion) and then that `float` get converted via the `Test(float number)` constructor. This then allows `operator*(Test a, Test b)` to be used.

To stop this, you make the constructor `explicit` like

```
explicit Test(float number){
    x = number;
}
```

Comment: Just to be clear, the conversion sequence is `int->float->Test`. That's one numerical conversion and one user-defined conversion.

Comment: @MSalters Good point.  Missed it was an `int`.  I've updated the answer, let me know what you think.